# Am I using "feature" correctly here?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

> I have many **features** that advance my changes to create a successful business in the future.

Is *features* correct here? Or there is something better?

Comment: Please remember to capitalize the word *I* and the first word in a sentence in your questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that "features" is wrong, and "skills" would be better. But, this is assuming that by "changes" you mean chances.

Whereas features would imply things like a person's looks ("he has very pronounced facial features") and usually applies to things instead of people ("this software has many features to improve productivity") skills imply a person's abilities to do things. EG, "I have good people skills" would imply that I'm good at working with people, relating to them, communicating with them, etc...

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Please don't solicit email addresses from our members. We have a chat room (click the *chat* link at the top of any page on the site) where you can chat with other members and ask questions if you like. But comments are not the place to ask more questions, and asking our members for personal information is not appropriate. Thank you.